# No definition found for function in vendor vscode

Tags: php, configuration, visual-studio-code, gitignore

My vscode does not see the definition of functions in vendor library. 
I don't know if it has anything to do with gitignore, where I have put vendor, but I would like to find a solution that lets me keep it in gitignore, but allows me to search through in the work environment.
Because it does not see the definition, it gets underlined as a problem and I can not take a peak into what I am working here with.
It does not affect the resulting outcome, it is problem while using the vscode.
Can you please help?

I tried creating config.json in the project root folder .vscode saying:

```html
{
    "search.useIgnoreFiles": false
}
```

It didn't do anything.
Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the direcory path into intelephense configuration:

```
@ext:bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client
```

Like here into **include path** list:

[image: intelephense workplace config]

Comment: Solved with Intelephense settings Add Item, thanks :)